# Getting the JSP URI that was sent to the GET/POST of a Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Is there a way to get the URI of a JSP that sent a particular GET/POST request to a Servlet?  I know of the `request.getRequestURI()` function within a Servlet, but that is just returning the URI of the Servlet itself.

For example:

Let's say that index.jsp sent the request to the Servlet SampleServlet.  I want to get the URI of the index.jsp file.  I haven't found a way to do it, any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit:

For those curious, it's just `request.getHeader('referer');`.  Thanks to Vinay Sajip for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Referer` header from the incoming request.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the JSP add the current URL as a value in the request scope before forwarding to or including the servlet?